# How can you tell Angular to send the Origin header?

Tags: angular, cors

I have an Angular application that connects with my server.  For internal reasons I want to be able to send the origin domain to the server as it can be accessed from a couple places, for example:

`https://domain1.com/app`
`https://domain2.com/app`

In order to do that I would like my Angular app to set the Origin header.  I have an interceptor and I tried to do something like this:

`return next.handle(req.clone({setHeaders: {Origin: environment.origin}}));`

However, it throws an error that says `Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"`.  I understand why, but how can I tell Angular to include this header and set it to the current domain (or just set it how it normally would)?  I don't need it set to anything special, I just need it included.

Comment: Are your backend and frontend on the same Web origin?

Comment: No they aren't, at least not in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Origin header is sent automatically (by the browser) on cross-origin Ajax requests (and on some other cross-origin requests such as those for fonts or involving the `crossorigin` attribute).

It isn't sent for same-origin requests, and you can't make it be sent because it is a Forbidden header (so websites can't lie about the Origin to bypass CORS checks).

Since it *is* set for cross-origin requests you can treat its **absence** as a signal that the request is a **same origin** request. Test for that instead.

---

Obviously, if the request does not come from a browser then it typically won't have an Origin header, but you can't depend on that for security as any non-browser source for a request could easily forge the Origin header.

Comment: Ok great thank you!  I tried some tests and didn't see it in the request headers so I assumed it wasn't being set.  However, I think they were same origin so that would explain why.  I did just try some cross origin requests in chrome and firefox and they do seem to be set so I think that gives me what I need to know!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the header you should set instead is `Referer`. [The usage description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) of this header fits your scenario really well.

You could also track the access patterns on your server using a fully custom header too.

Comment: That does seem to fit really well...  Thank you I will look at using that.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot set the header Origin from the Front end as its technically forbidden to do it from angular. Most browsers follow [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) where its not allowed to cross-communicate with different domain and these restriction is eased only if the domain is allowed access from the server.

But the CORS  issue can be resolved only through server side by setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to whatever domain you want to enable the access. Some example by using Nodejs

```
const app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://domain1.com/app');

    next();
});
```